# XSLT - get sub-string before given position in a text() node

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have an xml node like this in a document,

```
<full>Solid biofuels - Determination of moisture content - Oven dry method - Part 2: Total moisture - Simplified method</full>
```

NOTE: text() node within `<full>` can be anything. There can be any number of `-` can appear within `<full>`

Expected output is,

```
<full>
    <p1>Solid biofuels - Determination of moisture content - Oven dry method -</p1>
    <p2>Part 2: Total moisture - Simplified method</p2>
</full>
```

I need to get the content before the 3rd `-` for `<p1>`and rest of the content should go within `<p2>`.

I'm using XSLT to to this. I've tried with XSLT regex, tokanize() function, substring() functions but unable to find a proper method.

```
<xsl:template match="full">
    <full>
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(.,'-')">
            <p1>
                <xsl:if test="position()=1 or position()=2">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
            </p1>
            <p2>
                <xsl:if test="position() gt 2">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
            </p2>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </full>
</xsl:template>
```

Can anyone suggest me a method to do this.

Comment: Can you show the code you have currently tried, as you might not be far off in your attempts, and it is easier to correct your attempt, rather than write code from scratch. Thanks!

Comment: @TimC, Added sample codes I've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you might do it with `tokenize`

```
<xsl:template match="full">
  <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:variable name="tokens" select="tokenize(text(), ' - ')" />
      <xsl:variable name="tokenCount" select="count($tokens)" />
      <p1>
          <xsl:value-of select="$tokens[position() le 3]" separator=" - " />
          <xsl:if test="$tokenCount > 3"> - </xsl:if>
      </p1>
      <xsl:if test="$tokenCount > 3">
        <p2>
          <xsl:value-of select="$tokens[position() gt 3]" separator=" - " />
        </p2>
      </xsl:if>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!